# Convert MySQL Query to Laravel query

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I would to convert mysql query to laravel query.

MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM scadenze WHERE created_at IN(SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM scadenze GROUP BY processo_id)
```

Laravel ( i got an error, **Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string**):

```
DB::table('scadenze')->whereIn('created_at', DB::select("( SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM scadenze GROUP BY processo_id )"))->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DB::table('scadenze')->whereIn('created_at', function($query) {
   $query->from('scadenze')
         ->groupBy('processo_id')
         ->select(DB::raw('max(created_at)');
})->get();
```

Comment: New error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression::groupBy()

Comment: Try calling `groupBy` first then `select`, i've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
DB::table('scadenze')
    ->whereRaw(DB::raw("created_at IN (SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM scadenze GROUP BY processo_id)"))
    ->get();
```

I hope this can help!

Comment: I insert variable into dd(); but i got another error:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM scadenze GROUP BY processo_id' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `scadenze` where created_at IN SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM scadenze GROUP BY processo_id)

Comment: I've updated my answer, missing parentheses in the IN